# how to not round up decimal in c#.net

Tags: c#, sql-server-2008

I want my output is not rounded up whenever I put values in my TextBox. For example 5000/2000 the output I want to display is 2 but It displays 3.

Here is my **Code**

```
private void InsertReceipt()
{
    decimal Stub;

    Stub = decimal.Parse(txtAmount.Text) / 2000;

    SqlCommand cmd = new SqlCommand();
    cmd.Connection = cn;
    cmd.CommandType = CommandType.Text;
    cmd.CommandText = "INSERT INTO Ticket(CustomerID, Date, Store, Amount, NoStub)" + "VALUES (@CustomerID, @Date, @Store, @Amount, @NoStub) ";
    cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@CustomerID", txtCustomerID.Text);
    cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@Date", dtpDate.Value.Date.ToString());
    cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@Store", txtStore.Text);
    decimal amount = decimal.Parse(txtAmount.Text);
    cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@Amount", amount);
    cmd.Parameters.Add("@NoStub", SqlDbType.Decimal).Value = Stub;

    cmd.ExecuteNonQuery();
}
```

Comment: What output? Your decimal value `Stub` is only used as a SQL parameter, and your code seems fine to me - it's possible your table schema stores `decimal` without any decimal information stored. Can you provide us your exact `CREATE TABLE` command? (SSMS > %table% > Tasks > Script to).

Answer (score 6, accepted):

I think Math.Floor is what you're searching for:

```
Stub = Math.Floor(decimal.Parse(txtAmount.Text) / 2000);
```

Floor() always rounds down.

Comment: As a note I would add that `-2.5` will become `-3` and casting to an int will truncate it to `-2`.

Answer (score 0):

If you divide 2 numbers and assign to an integer, the result will be truncated (which is what you want):

```
decimal d = 5000 / 2000;
int i = (int)d;
Console.WriteLine(i);
```

Answer (score 0):

if you want your output to be integer then why you use decimal data type???

```
int stud = 5000/2000;
```

you will get your output directly in Integer (rounded)

Comment: This will not compile because the input is a `decimal` which must be cast to an `int`.

Answer (score 0):

I guess you want Stub value in decimal only but don't want rounded

For this you can use Use  `Math.Floor` which returns the largest integer less than or equal to the specified number.

```
Stub = Math.Floor(decimal.Parse(txtAmount.Text) / 2000);
```